# reverse an array in java using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am just starting to learn recursion and was able to use it write a simple factorial program without much of a problem. Now I am trying to write a recursive method that writes an array in reverse order but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. What am I missing? Thank you.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Recursion {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int myArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  }

  public static void reverseDisplay(int[] ary, int position){
    if(position > 0)
      System.out.print(ary[position]);
     reverseDisplay(ary, position - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what is going wrong, preferably with some examples.

Comment: Maybe `System.out.print(ary[position-1]);` ? The ending condition `if(position > 0)` seems to suggest that.

Comment: When I run the code I have no output at all.

Comment: Where is your call to reverseDisplay in main?
call it !

Comment: Well, you never actually *call* `reverseDisplay`, so that would be why. Could you try testing the function itself?

Comment: You're right I wasn't calling it in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You do not call your recursion method.
- You have an endless recursion because `reverseDisplay()` is always
  being executed due to missing enclosing brackets.
- Also your stop condition has to be `>= 0` because the first index of an array is 0.

Your method should read:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int myArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

        reverseDisplay(myArray, myArray.length -1);
    }

    public static void reverseDisplay(int[] ary, int position){
        if(position >= 0) {
            System.out.print(ary[position]);
            reverseDisplay(ary, position - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand what I did wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

When doing recursion you need something called a base case. You need the base case to end the recursion or you will get a stack overflow.

You might try something like this. The `return` statement stops the recursion from being endless.

```
public static void reverseDisplay(int[] ary, int position){
     if(int == -1)
         return;
     System.out.print(ary[position]);
     reverseDisplay(ary, position - 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Recursion {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int myArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    reverseDisplay(myArray,0);
  }

  public static void reverseDisplay(int[] ary, int position){
    if(position == ary.length){
        return;
    }

    reverseDisplay(ary, position + 1);
    System.out.print(ary[position]);
  }
}
```

If `position == ary.length` you finish the recursion, else you call `reverseDisplay` recursively and after that print the current position of `ary`.